# How to set orderCells to the middle row in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). I would like the sorting to be linked to the second span row, meaning that sorting is enabled on the **Name** cell and not on **Dummy**.

[image]

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    orderCellsTop: true, //move sorting to top header
  });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Dummy</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name1</th>
        <th>Position1</th>
        <th>Office1</th>
        <th>Age1</th>
        <th>Start date1</th>
        <th>Salary1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    .....
```

Here is a [live demo](http://live.datatables.net/yejelujo/103/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little bit of tweak

- Add `colspan=2` to **Dummy** header:

  ```
  <th colspan="2">Dummy</th>
  ```
- Now add an empty header just after **Name** and **Name1** headers:

  ```
  <th>Name</th>
  <th></th>
  ```
- Likewise, add an empty column to each row next to **Name** column:

  ```
  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
  <td></td>
  ```
- Finally, add `columnDefs` option to the DataTables intialization:

  ```
  columnDefs: [{ 
    visible: false, 
    targets: 1 
  }]
  ```

---

Final code will look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    orderCellsTop: true,
    columnDefs: [{
      visible: false,
      targets: 1
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Dummy</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th></th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Name1</th>
          <th></th>
          <th>Position1</th>
          <th>Office1</th>
          <th>Age1</th>
          <th>Start date1</th>
          <th>Salary1</th>
        </tr>

      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>


      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```